# Android InAppBilling onServiceConnected never called

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Trying to add some in app purchasing to an app I'm working on but things aren't going to so well.

I've got a FragmentActivity like this:

```
public class TestInAppBilling extends FragmentActivity{

//Application context reference
private static Context context;

/*
Billing stuff
 */
private IInAppBillingService mService;
private ServiceConnection mServiceConn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    if(mServiceConn == null){
        mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                mService = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                                           IBinder service) {
                mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
                System.out.println("Bound!");
            }
        };

        context.bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"), mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mServiceConn != null) {
        unbindService(mServiceConn);
    }
}
}
```

But for some reason the onServiceConnected callback never happens.

Anyone know whats causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you solved it. Anyway I had the same problem and I just fixed it. 
To make it work delete this line:

```
context.bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"), mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

And add this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
context = getApplicationContext();
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
getContext().bindService(intent, mServiceConn, getActivity().BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```